# How to calculate the time at which two circles will touch externally?

Tags: math, 2d, physics

This might be more of a math question than a programming question, but here goes.

I am trying come up with a formula for when two circles will touch each other in 2D space, given the starting positions, the radii, and the forces (such as gravity) working on the circles. I have been able to come up with a formula, but I'm trying to figure out if it can be solved for "t" (time).

```
var c1r, // radius of circle #1
    c1x, // x position of circle #1 at time 0
    c1y, // y position of circle #1 at time 0
    c1vx, // x velocity of circle #1 at time 0
    c1vy, // y velocity of circle #1 at time 0
    c1fx, // x force (such as gravity) on circle #1 at time 0
    c1fy; // y force (such as gravity) on circle #1 at time 0

var c2r, // radius of circle #2
    c2x, // x position of circle #2 at time 0
    c2y, // y position of circle #2 at time 0
    c2vx, // x velocity of circle #2 at time 0
    c2vy, // y velocity of circle #2 at time 0
    c2fx, // x force (such as gravity) on circle #2
    c2fy; // y force (such as gravity) on circle #2
```

Given those, I know I need to figure out when the circle centers are the sum of the radii apart.

```
var targetDist = c1r + c2r;
```

I know the trajectory formula for an individual circle:

```
function c1_position(t) (
    return {
        x: c1x + (c1vx * t) + (.5 * c1fx * Math.pow(t, 2)),
        y: c1y + (c1vy * t) + (.5 * c1fy * Math.pow(t, 2))
    }
 }
```

And of course, the distance formula:

```
function distance(c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c2x - c1x, 2) + Math.pow(c2y - c1y, 2));
}
```

Combining those two formulas, and with time (t) as an unknown:

```
var t;

Math.pow(targetDist, 2) = Math.pow((c2x + (c2vx * t) + (.5 * c2fx * Math.pow(t, 2))) - (c1x + (c1vx * t) + (.5 * c1fx * Math.pow(t, 2))), 2) + Math.pow((c2y + (c2vy * t) + (.5 * c2fy * Math.pow(t, 2))) - (c1y + (c1vy * t) + (.5 * c1fy * Math.pow(t, 2))), 2);
```

What I need to do is solve this for time (t). I wasn't able to figure out how to do it, so I've been using a brute force method to do it. Can this be solved for t, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

At first: we can transform problem of circle touching into problem of touching big circle `(r=r1+r2)` and  point

Second: To simplify equations a bit, we can apply Galileo principle: work in moving system connected to one center. This system is not inertial, but it is not important for collision calculations.

So fix the first circle center as stationary point (0,0) and find a moment, when the second center is at distance `r=r1+r2`. In this coordinate system starting position, relative velocity, relative acceleration are

```
 x0 = c2x - c1x
 y0 = c2y - c1y
 vx = c2vx - c1vx
 vy = c2vy - c1vy
 ax = c2fx - c1fx   //I assume that force is really acceleration (force/mass)
 ay = c2fy - c1fy
```

Now using equation of moving of point we can get formula for collision moment like yours:

```
r^2 = (x0 + vx*t+ ax*t^2/2)^2 + (y0 + vy*t+ ay*t^2/2)^2
```

Open parentheses:

```
r^2 = x0^2 + vx^2*t^2 + ax^2*t^4/4 + 2*x0*vx*t + 2*vx*ax*t^2/2 + 2*vx*ax*t^3/2 + 
      y0^2 + vy^2*t^2 + ay^2*t^4/4 + 2*y0*vy*t + 2*vy*ay*t^2/2 + 2*vy*ay*t^3/2
or
      t^4 * 1/4*(ax^2 + ay^2) + 
      t^3 * (vx*ax + vy*ay) +
      t^2 * (vx^2 + vy^2 + vx*ax + vy*ay) + 
      t *   (vx^2 + vy^2 + 2*x0*vx + 2*y0*vy) +
            (x0^2 + y0^2 - r^2) = 0
```

This is quartic equation for unknown `t`. It might be solved analytically and give from 0 to 4 real solutions. [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots). No doubts that you can easily find ready JS code/library intended for this purpose.

Root with the lowest positive `t` value *(if initially circles were apart!)* is the moment of touching